# removing zwnj character from string in postgres during select statement

Tags: postgresql, unicode, width, zero

The utf encoded string contains Zwnj(zero width non joiner) at the end and is stored in database.
Is it possible to remove that character during select statement. I tried trim() but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (x text);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (E'abc');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (E'foo\u200C');  -- U+200C = ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
SELECT x, octet_length(x) FROM test;
  x  │ octet_length 
─────┼──────────────
 abc │            3
 foo │            6
(2 rows)

CREATE TABLE test2 AS SELECT replace(x, E'\u200C', '') AS x FROM test;
SELECT x, octet_length(x) FROM test2;
  x  │ octet_length 
─────┼──────────────
 abc │            3
 foo │            3
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `replace(your_column, 'Zwnj','')` instead of trim()

Comment: @ahwnn Doesn't work. I have tried replace(kan_text,'zwnj',''), replace(kan_text,'&Zwnj',''). When query is executed there is a character at the end that looks like pipe symbol.

Comment: zwnj was the example you gave us (I have no idea what that should be). Of course you need to replace that with the real character(s) you want to replace.

Comment: @kiranking: You probably want to write an escaped string literal so you can use a backslash escape sequence hex or Unicode to represent the character.  Something like `replace(your_column, E'\u9876','')` (replacing `9876` with the Unicode literal). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE